# "required" attribute issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I gave `"required"` attribute for some input fields in one section of my .aspx page, so that the button inside that section need to validate this field. There are other buttons in some other section of the same page.

Now the issue is this field in getting validated in all the button click event. I was able to resolve this issue by giving `"formnovalidate"` attribute to the remaining buttons in the Page.

Is there is any other(better!) way i can solve this issue?

I don't want to compromise with `"required"` attribute by writing some javacsript validations.
Also i don't want to write any code/add any attribute in other buttons in the Page.
Is there is any other better solution to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you forgot to declare the `<form>`? Could you show us (the relevant parts of) your code?

Comment: <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="OpenShadowBox" formnovalidate  
            onclick="Button1_Click" />
      <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="OpenShadowBox" 
            onclick="Button2_Click"  />
    </div>  </form>  Is there is any other way to handle this?

Comment: The problem is that HTML5 form validation and the asp.net web forms 'one form to rule them all' model are incompatible if you want several forms on a page. You will need javascript to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use validationgroup [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx)

Comment: Please verify the issue,here the case is different,i am not using RequiredFieldValidator..!

Answer (score 0):

There was a simple solution,which i missed:

```
        function assignAttribute() {
        var b1 = document.getElementById('txtName');
        b1.setAttribute("required", "reqired");
        }
```

We can assign "required" attribute  through a javascript function on the OnClientClick of the button.